# Outgoing connection via proxy with Dataverse

Tags: azure, proxy, azure-functions, dataverse, serviceclient

Our client wants to use their own proxy (url) to connect to the Dataverse or at least the outgoing connection has to go through their proxy. We are use an Azure Function where the current connection we use an IOrganizationService object and it is instantiated with ServiceClient where we pass the ClientSecret, ClientId as parameters.

Is there any way to put that proxy url into the connection?

Thank you very much for the help.

The current connection we have:

```
try {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        IOrganizationService service = null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(initialUSer)) {
                service = new ServiceClient($ @ "AuthType=ClientSecret;url={myOrgUrl};ClientId={myClientId};ClientSecret={myClientSecret}");
        } else {
                service = new ServiceClient($ @ "AuthType=ClientSecret;url={myOrgUrl};ClientId={myClientId};ClientSecret={myClientSecret}") {
                        CallerId = new Guid(initialUSer)
                };
        }

        return service;
} catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception("Error connecting to Dynamics 365: " + ex);
}
```

Before returning the service, can the proxy be added somewhere in the outgoing connection?